# Scala regex can't match "\r\n" in a giving string which contains multiple "\r\n"

Tags: regex, scala

I want split `abcd\r\nabc\r\nppp` to `(abcd\r\nabc, ppp)` with regex `"(.*)\r\n(.*)".r`.

but the regex match fail as this:

```
object Regex extends App {
  val r = "(.*)\r\n(.*)".r
  val str = "abcd\r\nabc\r\nppp"

  str match {
    case r(a,b) =>
      println((a,b))
    case _ =>
      println("fail - ")
  }
}
```

console print `fail -`.

It works fine if use the Regex match `abcd\r\nppp`, code again:

```
object Regex extends App {
  val r = "(.*)\r\n(.*)".r
  val str = "abcd\r\nppp"

  str match {
    case r(a,b) =>
      println((a,b))
    case _ =>
      println("fail - ")
  }
}
```

Besides, I don't want replace \r\n to other characters.It's waste calculate resource, because the code is used to performance sensitive stage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot does not match `\n` by default (don't ask why - there is no reason, it just doesn't), so `.*` fails on the second `\n`. 
You can change that by specifying a `DOTALL` flag to your regex. That's done by adding `(?s)` to the beginning of the pattern (don't ask how `?s` came to stand for DOTALL ... there is a lot of mystery like this in regex world):

```
 val r = "(?s)(.*)\r\n(.*)".r
 val str = "abcd\r\nabc\r\nppp"
 str match {
    case r(a,b) => println(a -> b)
 }
```

This prints 
   (abcd
    abc,
    ppp
   )

If you want to split at the first `\r\n` rather than the last one add `?` to the the first group:

```
val r = "(?s)(.*?)\r\n(.*)".r
```

This makes wildcard non-greedy, so that it'll match the shortest possible string, rather than the longest, which is the default.

Comment: You are really good :)